# Cannot run load test using remote controller

Tags: asp.net, load-testing

I've created some web performance tests in Visual Studio 2012. And ensured they run fine locally. Then I've bundled them in a test mix in a load test and they run fine locally.

When I run them using my remote test settings, I get this error:
[image]

In the Agent column is my machine name (where VS is being run from).

I then created a test settings file to use a remote controller to do the testing. Here's how it looks:

General tab:
[image]

Roles tab:
[image]

Data and Diagnostics tab:
[image]

Deployment tab is empty (nothing added).

Setup and Cleanup Scripts have no scripts in them.

Hosts tab:
[image]

Test Timeout tab:
[image]

Unit Test tab is empty (not unit tests or folders are added.

Web Test tab:
[image]

The controller is in another machine (also has an agent in the same machine). Here are the controller settings:

[image]

And here are the agent settings (same machine as the controller):

[image]

So, does any one know why I'm getting that error at the top when I run remote load tests using this controller?

Cheers and thank you!

Comment: Any joy with this, I am having exactly the same issue!

Comment: I don't think I solved it. Sorry.